# Metro In App Purchase

Tags: microsoft-metro, marketplace

Will the new Metro API support in app purchases?  We will be selling an app in the Microsoft Marketplace that requires a monthly subscription.  Is there a model for doing this in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Windows Store In App purchase, or your own purchase model -- unlike the apple app store, you aren't mandated to use Microsofts IAP. However, there are restrictions such as being PCI compliant.

A good launching point for understanding the options is the windows store blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/07/20/making-money-with-your-apps-through-the-windows-store.aspx

For auto renew options, your gonna have to use PayPal, or stripe. Stripe appears to be the simplest API to work with.

Comment: Ok, I read that, along with another post.  That just leaves support for subscription services.  Is that natively supported?

Comment: You mean auto renew with the store transaction itself? I dont believe thats currently possible using the store API's -- you'd have to use PayPal's monthly subscription offerings to perform the transaction in this case.